# how to make camera move back every time player moves to up?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want every step the player moves up the camera to move back one step in position z, and also the opposite when the player falls down.....
I really need someone to answer me I am new to making games and this problem stay with me for a long time so if anyone can help I will be so happy about that!!

So how to do it??

Comment: What you are describing can be done many ways, your current question is very vague. Perhaps if you included the code you have tried, it would provide more context for an answer.

Comment: Sorry but we won't do this for you. You need to atleast try.
 Watch a tutorial or atleast google player camera script.

Comment: please provide a script of your current attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can do this step to do the following task:

In your movement script get reference of your camera.
In your up movement function move your camera back in z axis by subtracting the amount you want camera to move :

`float Step = 1; Camera.transofrm.position = new Vector3(Camera.transofrm.position.x,Camera.transofrm.position.y,Camera.transofrm.position.z-Step);`

With this line of code your camera will go back in z each time player move up.
Do the same for fall down by just adding value to y axis of camera :

`Camera.transofrm.position = new Vector3(Camera.transofrm.position.x,Camera.transofrm.position.y+Step,Camera.transofrm.position.z);`